# Accidentally Deleted Block Special File (/dev/sdb)

Tags: 13.10, nautilus, usb-drive

I accidentally deleted block special file `/dev/sdb` trying to wipe my usb thumbdrive. Now `/dev/sdb` is not listed under `fdisk -l`, but the thumdrive still opens in file manager when I insert it to the port.

So, I want to know if there's a fix, or what the consequences are (I can't apply operations to `dev/sdb` in terminal, for one thing).

Many thanks,

The command I used to delete was:

```
sudo rm -R -i /dev/sdb
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the same operation on my system and there's no consequences as `/dev/sdb` will be recreated if you unplug/plug again your device.

You won't be able to eject your device cleanly though as the block device has been deleted. So if there's no I/O operations in progress just unplug it and replug. Otherwise wait till a possible copy operation has finished.